# Is the coordinate ring of an elliptic curve principal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ a field, $E$ an elliptic curve. I would like to know if the coordinate ring of $K[E]=K[X,Y]/(E)$ is principal. I think the answer is no. I tried to prove that the ideal $J=\langle y,x^2\rangle$ which is included in $K[E]$ is not principal but this ideal is $K[E].$ So iam stuck.
By advance thank you.

Comment: Elliptic curves are projective, not affine. What do you call "elliptic curves"? Anyway, whatever your (reasonable) definition is, I guarantee that your coordinate ring will be non principal !

Comment: My teacher works with affine elliptic curves defined by the equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b.$ But even I homogenize the polynomial $Y^2-X^3-aX-b,$ to make this curve a projective elliptic curve, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The coordinate ring $K[E]$  of your affine curve $E$ is not principal because it has a  non zero Picard group whereas a PID (or even a UFD) has trivial Picard group.